# composer-php install failed

Tags: php, composer-php

(wamp on Windows)
I've composer.phar and composer.bat in c:\bin (Path variable is OK)

letting composer command from cmd window I get: "php  is not an internal or external command"

after setting the PHP directory in the PATH, PHP server will have complained: it will work improperly by reason of PATH variable.

How can I reach @php command from anywhere without setting PHP directory in the PATH

(I've the save problem width PHPUnit installing)

Thx a lot

Comment: It's easier to have `php.exe` in the path, but otherwise you could do `C:\wamp\bin\php.exe C:\bin/composer.phar install`. Note that the path to PHP is only an example there.